# Display dictionary values in template

Tags: django, django-templates

Hi I have very basic question. 
I have view like below:

```
def view1:
    dict = ('one':'itemone','two':'itemtwo','three','itemthree')
    return render_to_response('test.html',dict)
```

test.html

```
<body>
{% for key,value in dict.items %}{{ value }}{% endfor %}
</body>
```

it doesn't work. Can anyone suggest the correct method to iterate dictionary values in a template. Thanks in advance. Once again am sorry for my basic question.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you want

```
def view1:
   d = {'one':'itemone', 'two':'itemtwo', 'three':'itemthree'}
   return render_to_response('test.html', {'d':d})
```

and

```
<body>
 {% for key,value in d.items %}{{ value }}{% endfor %}
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your dictionary syntax is off. Try this:

```
my_dict = {'one':'itemone','two':'itemtwo','three':'itemthree'}
```

(I'd call it something other than `dict` so you're not overriding python's `dict` type.)