# How to get year from date field(MySQL Database) and display it in a calendar view django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I want to get year from date field(MySQL Database) and display it in a calendar view as per the below image:

[image]

Given below is my model class:

```
YEAR_CHOICES = []
for r in range(1980, (datetime.datetime.now().year+1)):
    YEAR_CHOICES.append((r,r))
    
class Persons(models.Model): 
     
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    salary = models.IntegerField
    doj = models.DateField(choices=YEAR_CHOICES, default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
    class Meta:
        db_table = "test"
```

Instead of only year I am getting data like "Oct. 7, 2021". I want only year neither month or date.
And display it in a calender view, like the above image.

Here the year values are retrieved from the mysql database.

Any help will be highly appreciated!
Thank You!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified the queryset to get distinct year from datetime column and it works perfectly for me:

```
def calender(request):
    dateofjoining = Persons.objects.extra(select={"doj": "EXTRACT(YEAR FROM doj)"}).distinct().values_list("doj", flat=True)
    
    person = {
        "Years": dateofjoining
    }
    print(person["Years"][0])
    return render(request, "home.html", person)
```

But I am unable to display it in a calendar view.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried:

```
years={}
persons = Persons.objects.all()
for person in persons:
   years[person.firstname]=person.doj.year
```

Comment: I tried your code: def calender(request):
    years={}
    persons = Persons.objects.all()
    for person in persons:
        years.append(person.doj.year)
    return render(request, "home.html", years)     but getting error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: try: years[person.firstname]=person.doj.year instead of append

Comment: But how to display this value in a div(html)?

Comment: try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7838322/10377102